# Adding a Service Reference to my WCF Service breaks my .net website

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have create a WCF Service and successfully added to 2 of my websites with no problem.

I have now tried to add the reference to two other websites and it breaks things. It kills other referenced services, creates errors about references not being found.

In of them its:

> Reference.svcmap: Could not load type 'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.SanitizerProvider' from assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=18.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.

In another its:

> App_WebReferences/ServiceReference1/(1): Build (web): Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'ClientDependency.Core, Version=1.9.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

As soon as I remove the new reference, the build runs smoothly.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Looks to me that you have run into version hell with 3rd party libraries.  Check to ensure all projects are using the same version of 3rd party packages

Comment: What is the version of Netframework in your project?

Comment: @MickyD Only matching libraries is NewtonSoft JSon and they match

Comment: @AbrahamQian Both are 4.7.2

Comment: If WCF service could not work properly in the web app, I suggest you call the service by establishing a channel factory.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/channel-factory
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory

Comment: I managed to solve it. I uninstalled and reinstalled my 3rd party stuff and it worked